# Emberjs rename '/' route

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-router

I often used routes with the path `'/'` to specify them as the default route.
Now I noticed that it didnt work as expected with the link-to helper.

I used this in an older version of emberjs and I think it worked.

So when I have a `language` route with a dynamic segment which contains a `courceCategories` route that has the path `'/'` and use the `{{#link-to "language" model}}click{{/link-to}}` helper I get the following error:

```
Assertion failed: The attempt to link-to route 'language' failed (also tried 'language.index'). The router did not find 'language' in its possible routes: 'loading', 'error', 'languages', 'language.loading', 'language.error', 'language.courceCategories', 'index'
```

Why cant the router resolve this url?

demonstration: http://emberjs.jsbin.com/umeFeBe/2/edit

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in Ember, and it's been reported [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3913).

[This PR](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/4196) should fix this, Try with the canary build once the PR is merged.

UPDATE: The PR has been merged, and this works now, check [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/umeFeBe/8/edit)

Comment: Ha perfect, thanks :D
So I will use the workaround from @claptimes until this is in the productive build.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're overriding the `language.index` value when you do the route `/` path inside its function. You now need to link to `language.courceCategories`

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="languages">
  {{#each this}}
    {{#link-to "language.courceCategories" this}}{{id}}{{/link-to}}
  {{/each}}
</script>
```